# Wordpress Plugin Problem with $_GET not returning value

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I am writing a plugin for wordpress, first step of that plugin is to set a cookie to the value of url param `?r=` if it exists.

```
public function init_query_params() {
        if(!isset($_GET['r'])) {
            return;
        }

        $cookie_name = 'waitlist_referrer_id';
        $cookie_value = $_GET['r'];
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    }
```

The problem is that `$_GET` is empty even when the param DOES exist. The param is visible in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but not in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

This problem only persist on staging/prod for this particular client, it works in my local environment and another clients prod environment.

For the time being and I am just parsing it from `REQUEST_URI` but would love help tracking down the real issue.

Comment: Does $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] exists (has any value)?

Comment: Is there any URL rewriting involved here?

Comment: Try to use $_REQUEST['r'] it contains the contents for all POST GET and COOKIE

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your plugin or function file.

```
function add_query_vars_cb($aVars) {
$aVars[] = "r";
return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars_cb');
```

Then on page where you want to get the value of the query string variable, you should print this object

```
$objj = get_queried_object();
print_r($objj);
```

I think you will get the value.
Thank you.